# A link equivalent to a reset button?

Tags: javascript, button, hyperlink, reset

I want a 'delete link' equivalent of the button type="reset", but not a button, a link. Just like on the youtube comment box. How is this possible?

Answer (score 6):

You can call the `reset` method of a HTML form via Javascript:

```
<form id="myform">
<input type="text"/>
<a href="javascript:document.getElementById('myform').reset();">reset</a>
</form>
```

Comment: if there is not submit button then there is no use of form too.. :) and same this for reset too... :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this like youtube: :)

```
<textarea id="tarea"></textarea>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById('tarea').value='';">reset</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a normal button `<input type="reset" value="Reset" class="textbutton">`, but style it to look like normal text:

```
.textbutton {
  border: 0px;
  background-color: inherit;
}
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/bbGZ6/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to reset a form with a link, bind an onClick event to the link and have it call the **reset()** method on the form object.